# Had a segmentation at the end of execution of the program dunno what i'm doing wrong

Tags: c, sqlite, openbsd

I take sample.c of kcgi add sqlite3 and put what's in sendindex() into sqlite_exec() callback with adding some stuff.

struct kreq req is passed to callback.
Dunno if khtmlreq is good here but looks like yes.

```
/*  $Id$ */
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2014, 2015, 2017 Kristaps Dzonsons <kristaps@bsd.lv>
 *
 * Permission to use, copy, modify, and distribute this software for any
 * purpose with or without fee is hereby granted, provided that the above
 * copyright notice and this permission notice appear in all copies.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS" AND THE AUTHOR DISCLAIMS ALL WARRANTIES
 * WITH REGARD TO THIS SOFTWARE INCLUDING ALL IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF
 * MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHOR BE LIABLE FOR
 * ANY SPECIAL, DIRECT, INDIRECT, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES OR ANY DAMAGES
 * WHATSOEVER RESULTING FROM LOSS OF USE, DATA OR PROFITS, WHETHER IN AN
 * ACTION OF CONTRACT, NEGLIGENCE OR OTHER TORTIOUS ACTION, ARISING OUT OF
 * OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE USE OR PERFORMANCE OF THIS SOFTWARE.
 */
#include <sys/types.h> /* size_t, ssize_t */
#include <stdarg.h> /* va_list */
#include <stddef.h> /* NULL */
#include <stdint.h> /* int64_t */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> /* memset */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <kcgi.h>
#include <kcgihtml.h>

/*
 * Simple CGI application.
 * Compile it with `make samples` (or using gmake) and install it into
 * your web server's /cgi-bin.
 * The "template.xml" file should be in the /cgi-bin directory as well
 * and readable by the server process.
 * (Obviously this is just for a sample.)
 *
 * Assuming localhost/cgi-bin, the script is localhost/cgi-bin/sample.
 * The pages recognised are:
 *
 *   - /cgi-bin/sample/index.html
 *   - /cgi-bin/sample/template.html
 *   - /cgi-bin/sample/senddata.html
 *
 * See the sendindex et al. functions for what these do.
 */

/* Recognised page requests.  See pages[]. */
enum    page {
    PAGE_INDEX,
    PAGE_TEMPLATE,
    PAGE_SENDDATA,
    PAGE__MAX
};

/*
 * All of the keys (input field names) we accept. 
 * The key names are in the "keys" array.
 * See sendindex() for how these are used.
 */
enum    key {
    KEY_INTEGER, 
    KEY_FILE,
    KEY_PAGECOUNT,
    KEY_PAGESIZE,
    KEY__MAX
};

/*
 * The elements in our template file.
 * The element key names are in the "templs" array.
 * See sendtemplate() for how this is used.
 */
enum    templ {
    TEMPL_TITLE,
    TEMPL_NAME,
    TEMPL_REMOTE_ADDR,
    TEMPL__MAX
};

/*
 * We need a structure because we can't get the "r" from the request.
 * This is used by our template callback.
 */
struct  tstrct {
    struct khtmlreq  req;
    struct kreq *r;
};

/*
 * We'll use this to route pages by creating an array indexed by our
 * page.
 * Then when the page is parsed, we'll route directly into it.
 */
typedef void (*disp)(struct kreq *);

static void senddata(struct kreq *);
static void sendindex(struct kreq *);
static void sendtemplate(struct kreq *);

static const disp disps[PAGE__MAX] = {
    sendindex, /* PAGE_INDEX */
    sendtemplate, /* PAGE_TEMPLATE */
    senddata, /* PAGE_SENDDATA */
};

static const struct kvalid keys[KEY__MAX] = {
    { kvalid_int, "integer" }, /* KEY_INTEGER */
    { NULL, "file" }, /* KEY_FILE */
    { kvalid_uint, "count" }, /* KEY_PAGECOUNT */
    { kvalid_uint, "size" }, /* KEY_PAGESIZE */
};

/*
 * Template key names (as in @@TITLE@@ in the file).
 */
static const char *const templs[TEMPL__MAX] = {
    "title", /* TEMPL_TITLE */
    "name", /* TEMPL_NAME */
    "remote_addr", /* TEMPL_REMOTE_ADDR */
};

/* 
 * Page names (as in the URL component) mapped from the first name part
 * of requests, e.g., /sample.cgi/index.html -> index -> PAGE_INDEX.
 */
static const char *const pages[PAGE__MAX] = {
    "index", /* PAGE_INDEX */
    "template", /* PAGE_TEMPLATE */
    "senddata" /* PAGE_SENDDATA */
};

/*
 * Open an HTTP response with a status code and a particular
 * content-type, then open the HTTP content body.
 * You can call khttp_head(3) before this: CGI doesn't dictate any
 * particular header order.
 */
static void
resp_open(struct kreq *req, enum khttp http)
{
    enum kmime   mime;

    /*
     * If we've been sent an unknown suffix like '.foo', we won't
     * know what it is.
     * Default to an octet-stream response.
     */
    if (KMIME__MAX == (mime = req->mime))
        mime = KMIME_APP_OCTET_STREAM;

    khttp_head(req, kresps[KRESP_STATUS], 
        "%s", khttps[http]);
    khttp_head(req, kresps[KRESP_CONTENT_TYPE], 
        "%s", kmimetypes[mime]);
    khttp_body(req);
}

/*
 * Callback for filling in a particular template part.
 * Let's just be simple for simplicity's sake.
 */
static int
template(size_t key, void *arg)
{
    struct tstrct   *p = arg;

    switch (key) {
    case (TEMPL_TITLE):
        khtml_puts(&p->req, "title");
        break;
    case (TEMPL_NAME):
        khtml_puts(&p->req, "name");
        break;
    case (TEMPL_REMOTE_ADDR):
        khtml_puts(&p->req, p->r->remote);
        break;
    default:
        return(0);
    }

    return(1);
}

/*
 * Demonstrates how to use templates.
 * Returns HTTP 200 and the template content.
 */
static void
sendtemplate(struct kreq *req)
{
    struct ktemplate t;
    struct tstrct    p;

    memset(&t, 0, sizeof(struct ktemplate));
    memset(&p, 0, sizeof(struct tstrct));

    p.r = req;
    t.key = templs;
    t.keysz = TEMPL__MAX;
    t.arg = &p;
    t.cb = template;

    resp_open(req, KHTTP_200);
    khtml_open(&p.req, req, 0);
    khttp_template(req, &t, "template.xml");
    khtml_close(&p.req);
}

/*
 * Send a random amount of data.
 * Requires KEY_PAGECOUNT (optional), KEY_PAGESIZE (optional).
 * Page count is the number of times we flush a page (with the given
 * size) to the wire.
 * Returns HTTP 200 and the random data.
 */
static void
senddata(struct kreq *req)
{
    int64_t   i, j, nm, sz;
    char     *buf;

    nm = 1024 * 1024;
    if (NULL != req->fieldmap[KEY_PAGECOUNT])
        nm = req->fieldmap[KEY_PAGECOUNT]->parsed.i;
    if (0 == nm)
        nm = 1;

    sz = 1;
    if (NULL != req->fieldmap[KEY_PAGESIZE])
        sz = req->fieldmap[KEY_PAGESIZE]->parsed.i;
    if (0 == sz || (uint64_t)sz > SIZE_MAX)
        sz = 1;

    buf = kmalloc(sz);

    resp_open(req, KHTTP_200);
    for (i = 0; i < nm; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < sz; j++)
#ifndef __linux__
            buf[j] = 65 + arc4random_uniform(24);
#else
            buf[j] = 65 + (random() % 24);
#endif
        khttp_write(req, buf, sz);
    }

    free(buf);
}

/*
 * Demonstrates how to use GET and POST forms and building with the HTML
 * builder functions.
 * Returns HTTP 200 and HTML content.
 */
```

Here is the callback function including what was in sendindex() :

```
static int callback(void *ptr, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName) {
    struct kreq *req = (struct kreq *)ptr;

        char            *page;
        struct khtmlreq  r;
        const char      *cp;

        cp = NULL == req->fieldmap[KEY_INTEGER] ?
                "" : req->fieldmap[KEY_INTEGER]->val;
        kasprintf(&page, "%s/%s", req->pname, pages[PAGE_INDEX]);

        resp_open(req, KHTTP_200);
        khtml_open(&r, req, 0);
        khtml_elem(&r, KELEM_DOCTYPE);
        khtml_elem(&r, KELEM_HTML);
        khtml_elem(&r, KELEM_HEAD);
        khtml_elem(&r, KELEM_TITLE);
        khtml_puts(&r, "Welcome!");
        khtml_closeelem(&r, 2);
        khtml_elem(&r, KELEM_BODY);
        khtml_puts(&r, "Welcome!");
        khtml_attr(&r, KELEM_FORM,
                KATTR_METHOD, "post",
                KATTR_ENCTYPE, "multipart/form-data",
                KATTR_ACTION, page,
                KATTR__MAX);
        khtml_elem(&r, KELEM_FIELDSET);
        khtml_elem(&r, KELEM_LEGEND);
        khtml_puts(&r, "Post (multipart)");
        khtml_closeelem(&r, 1);
        khtml_elem(&r, KELEM_P);
        khtml_attr(&r, KELEM_INPUT,
                KATTR_TYPE, "number",
                KATTR_NAME, keys[KEY_INTEGER].name,
                KATTR_VALUE, cp, KATTR__MAX);
        khtml_closeelem(&r, 1);
        khtml_elem(&r, KELEM_P);
        khtml_attr(&r, KELEM_INPUT,
                KATTR_TYPE, "file",
                KATTR_MULTIPLE, "",
                KATTR_NAME, keys[KEY_FILE].name,
                KATTR__MAX);
        if (NULL != req->fieldmap[KEY_FILE]) {
                if (NULL != req->fieldmap[KEY_FILE]->file) {
                        khtml_puts(&r, "file: ");
                        khtml_puts(&r, req->fieldmap[KEY_FILE]->file);
                        khtml_puts(&r, " ");
                }
                if (NULL != req->fieldmap[KEY_FILE]->ctype) {
                        khtml_puts(&r, "ctype: ");
                        khtml_puts(&r, req->fieldmap[KEY_FILE]->ctype);
                }
        }
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<argc; i++){
    printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
    khtml_puts(&r, "OK");
  }

        khtml_closeelem(&r, 1);
        khtml_elem(&r, KELEM_P);
        khtml_attr(&r, KELEM_INPUT,
                KATTR_TYPE, "submit",
                KATTR__MAX);
        khtml_closeelem(&r, 0);
        khtml_close(&r);
        free(page);

}
```

Here is sendindex() function :

```
static void
sendindex(struct kreq *req)
{
    sqlite3 *db;
        char *zErrMsg = 0;
        int rc;
        rc = sqlite3_open("/var/www/MaSSH/databases/massh.db", &db);
        if(rc){
                sqlite3_close(db);
        }
        rc = sqlite3_exec(db, "SELECT * FROM hosts;", callback, &req, &zErrMsg);
        if(rc!= SQLITE_OK){
                sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
        }
        sqlite3_close(db);
}

int
main(void)
{
    struct kreq  r;
    enum kcgi_err    er;

    /* Set up our main HTTP context. */

    er = khttp_parse(&r, keys, KEY__MAX, 
        pages, PAGE__MAX, PAGE_INDEX);

    if (KCGI_OK != er)
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);

    /* 
     * Accept only GET, POST, and OPTIONS.
     * Restrict to text/html and a valid page.
     * If all of our parameters are valid, use a dispatch array to
     * send us to the page handlers.
     */

    if (KMETHOD_OPTIONS == r.method) {
        khttp_head(&r, kresps[KRESP_ALLOW], 
            "OPTIONS GET POST");
        resp_open(&r, KHTTP_200);
    } else if (KMETHOD_GET != r.method && 
           KMETHOD_POST != r.method) {
        resp_open(&r, KHTTP_405);
    } else if (PAGE__MAX == r.page || 
           KMIME_TEXT_HTML != r.mime) {
        resp_open(&r, KHTTP_404);
    } else
        (*disps[r.page])(&r);

    khttp_free(&r);
    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to determine where exactly the segmentation fault is occuring? Is it occuring in your code or inside sqlite?

Comment: This seems to lack the _minimal_ part of a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

If you run your code through a debugger you will see

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000b60dbbd86b6 in callback (ptr=0x7f7ffffeb878, argc=1, argv=0xb6317623210,azColName=0xb6317623208) at /tmp/so.c:262
262             cp = NULL == req->fieldmap[KEY_INTEGER] ?

(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000040c108fc6b6 in callback () from /home/dsp/a.out
#1  0x0000040e744f172a in sqlite3_exec () from /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so.37.7
#2  0x0000040c108fcb79 in sendindex () from /home/dsp/a.out
#3  0x0000040c108fccbe in main () from /home/dsp/a.out
```

that tells that that req is probably not holding what you think it's holding.
We see from looking at the source that the callback function does:

```
static int callback(void *ptr, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName) {
    struct kreq *req = (struct kreq *)ptr;
```

so the void * passed to it is not what it should be. we see from the backtrace that this is passed from the sqlite3_exec function.

It seems it requires the pointer to the request to be the 4th argument. A google search turns out [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60478714/im-not-able-to-pass-a-callback-function-with-a-new-argument-i-added-in-c) that you probably received yesterday from Chris Loonam and he correctly says that in setindex your code should pass the pointer to the req as the 4th argument like so

```
rc = sqlite3_exec(db, "SELECT * FROM hosts;", callback, req, &zErrMsg);
```

since that function takes req as

```
static void sendindex(struct kreq *req)
```

in your code you are passing it in sqlite3_exec as &req therefore it ends up being a pointer to a pointer of a request and the casting in the callback of course ends up leading to an invalid dereference.